# Best way to store a 2D-array with column and row names

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to find the best way to store in Redux a 2D array with row and column names.
In terms of priorities, I would rank code readability and maintainability above performance. Hence, accessing a value through `table[row][col]` would be preferable.

I have thought about two solutions:

- First, storing it in three distinct variables `colNames`, `rowNames` and `table`. Accessing values would still be doable. But, for example, removing a column would then require to modify both `colNames` and `rowNames`. Incrementing some value from row and column names would require to access all three variables.

```
var rowNames = ["row1", "row2", "row3"];
var colNames = ["col1", "col2", "col3"];
var table = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];
```

- The other way would be to store a single variable `table` as an Object. It becomes easy to access values. But it is harder to correctly update it in Redux to respect immutable state.

```js
var table = {
    row1: {
        col1: 1,
        col2: 2,
        col3: 3
    },
    row2: {
        col1: 4,
        col2: 5,
        col3: 6
    },
    row3: {
        col1: 7,
        col2: 8,
        col3: 9
    }
};
```

Some other idea would be to use [Immer JS](https://immerjs.github.io/) with the second solution to improve code readability.

What is then the best way to store such a value in Redux ?

### Solution I chose

I ended up using the second solution with a single variable. Once the modification of this table is properly made in Redux reducers, it makes accessing and displaying said table easy.

Answer (score 0):

I do think your solution is quite nice and adapted to rendering in an html table. However you will have to iterate over `Object.keys(table)` to go through the rows.
Another solution could be to do somehing like that so you can iterate over objects directly:

```
var table = [
    {
        name: "row1",
        col1: 1,
        col2: 2,
        col3: 3
    },
    {
        name: "row2",
        col1: 4,
        col2: 5,
        col3: 6
    },
    {
        name: "row3",
        col1: 7,
        col2: 8,
        col3: 9
    }
];
```

This solution also has it's problems: you have to specifically take the name property out of the object while iterating for rows. You would also have to iterate over Object.keys of the inner object avoiding the treatment of the "name" column.

Hope this help as an overview of your problem :)